# Manipulating a distance matrix for intersection over time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've created distance matrices for time steps at every 0.1 seconds for intervals of 60 seconds. The matrices look so for each time step with distance values populating them:

time = 0.1

```
    a1    b2     c3     d4
a1   0   5.4    9.1    10.1
b2  5.4    0    5.0     3.2
c3  9.1  5.0      0     6.6
d4  10.1 3.2    6.6       0
```

time = 0.2

```
    a1    b2     c3     d4
a1  0    2.4    9.1    12.1
b2  2.4   0     6.7     3.6
c3  9.1  6.7      0     9.6
d4  12.1 3.6    9.6       0
```

The goal is to generate an adjacency matrix, or neighbor list at the end of each 60 second interval (examining 600 dataframes) for neighbors that maintain a distance threshold the entire minute (in each distance matrix examined).

For example, if the distance limit is `d=10`,  then for this 0.2 second sample it would return a list of [a1, b2, c3] since for that 0.2 second interval, they all maintained a distance less than 10.

I was wondering if there is a semi-efficient or clever way to do this with pandas and python.

Comment: where are the other dataframes? are we looking at only one dataframe across two periods? also, is the expected output `a1,b2,c3` for `time=0.1`?

Comment: The other dataframes are in memory being read in one at a time (each 0.1 seconds). You are looking at 2 different dataframes at 2 different time intervals. The expected output is ```a1,b2,c3``` at the end of parsing the 2 dataframes. Ideally, will scale the concept up to parsing 600 of these dataframes and returning the list.

Comment: do we need to find the difference between these two dfs or do we need to filter each one separately? Did you include two time periods and two dfs to show that there are many dfs or are they connected?

Comment: The goal would be to find the common ```id``` fields in each dataframe that satisfy the ```d<=10``` constraint. So at ```time=0.01``` there is ```a1,b2,c3``` and at ```time=0.2``` there is also ```a1,b2,c3``` and they still satisfy ```d<=10```. Showing multiple df's to show time and distances are going to change and some values that met the constraint might not end up in the final result as they did not maintain that minimum distance between each other for the entire time duration in each different df parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stack your dataframes along a 3rd dimension, then apply your threshold to get boolean values, then use `numpy.logical_and.reduce` to apply the "and" along your third dimension.

eg if `dfs` is a list of your dataframes then do

```
threshold = 10
stacked = np.stack(dfs, axis=2)
result = np.logical_and.reduce(stacked < threshold, axis=2)
```

You can then put `result` inside a dataframe with index and column names if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, since you have a symmetric matrix, you can use `numpy` to create boolean masks and filter the indices (or columns) with it. Since it's symmetric, it suffices to analyze either the upper triangle or the lower triangle (I chose lower triangle). Then among the numbers in the lower triangle, build a mask that returns False for the rows that contain a value greater than `d`.

```py
import numpy as np
def get_neighbor_indices(df, d):
    less_than_d = np.tril(df.lt(d).to_numpy())
    upper_triangle_dummy = np.triu(np.ones(df.shape)==1)
    msk = (less_than_d | upper_triangle_dummy).all(axis=1)
    return df.index[msk].tolist()

>>> get_neighbor_indices(df1, 10)
['a1', 'b2', 'c3']
>>> get_neighbor_indices(df2, 10)
['a1', 'b2', 'c3']
```